# Continuously fetch data from database using Java

Tags: java, database

I have a scenario where my Java program has to continuously communicate with the database table, for example my Java program has to get the data of my table when new rows are added to it at runtime. There should be continuous communication between my program and database.

If the table has 10 rows initially and 2 rows are added by the user, it must detect this and return the rows.

My program shouldn't use AJAX and timers.

Comment: Are calls (adding rows) to the database being made through the Java program or through some other app?

Answer (score 3):

If the database you are using is Oracle, consider using [triggers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#ADFNS012), that call [java stored procedure](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/jsp/oracle9ijsp.html), that notifies your client of changes in the db (using [JMS](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/), [RMI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/rmi/index.jsp) or whatever you want).

Answer (score 2):

without Ajax and timers, it not seems to do this task.

I have also faced the same issue, where i need to push some data from server to client when it changes.

For this, you can user Server push AKA **"Comet"** programming.

In coment

- we make a channel between client and server, where client subscribes for particular channel.
- Server puts its data in the channel when it has it.
- when client reads the channel, it gets all the data in the channel and channel is emptied.
- so every time client reads from channel, it will get new data only.

Also to monitor DB changes, you can have two things,

1. Some trigger/timer (Check out `Quartz Scheduler`)
2. Event base mechanism, which pushes data in the channel on particular events.

basically, client can't know anything happening on server side, so you must push some data or event to tell client that, `i have some new data, please call some method`. Its kind of notification. So please check in comet/server push with event notification.

hope this helps.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not the simplest problem, really.

Let's divide it into 2 smaller problems:

1) how to enable reloading without timers and ajax

2) how to implement server side

1. There is no way to notify clients from the server. So, you need to use flash or silverlight or JavaFX or Applets to create a thick client. If the problem with Ajax is that you don't know how to use it for this problem then you can investigate some ready-to-use libraries of jsp tags or jsf components with ajax support.
2. If you have only 1 server then just add a cache. If there are several servers then consider using distributed caches.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a low-traffic database you could implement a thread that rapidly checks for updates to the DB (polling).

If you have a high-traffic DB i wouldn't recommend that, 'cause polling creates much additional traffic.

Answer (score 0):

server notifying client is not a good idea (consider a scenario with a 1000 clients). Do u use some persistence layer or u have to stick to pure JDBC?

Comment: yea i have a persistence layer and my database is DB2. kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have binary logs turned on in MYSQL , you can see all of the transactions that occur in the database.

Answer (score 0):

A portable way to do this, is adding a column time stamp (create date) which indicates when the row was added to the table. After initial loading of the content you simply poll for new content which a where clause current_time >= create_date. In case that rows could have identical timestamps you need to filter duplicates before adding them.